# Update to already published game on Google Play giving error with SHA1 key

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, sha1, google-play-games

I have a problem with my already published game at Google Play Store.
In my first published game I have not used any Google APIs.
But in my next update I have used Google Play Game Services.
Now I have uploaded updated APK for Alpha testing. When I have downloaded my app I get

> "The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer console. 
>   Also if the application...."

I have Googled it everywhere. And I got to know its SHA Key1 or Game key from the Google error.
I have checked the SHA1 key that is available in

```
Eclipse -Windows > Preferences > Android > Build = SHA1
```

This SHA1 key and the SHA1 key that I have given for OAuth 2.0 at Google API are the same.

But when I export my apk file to upload on Google Play, the SHA1 key generated at last is different than the one I have got in eclipse.

Can anybody help me solve the problem with the SHA1 keys?

Comment: In your first launch, when you create signed apk there was a debug.keystore file generate for you apk.You have to use same debug.keystore for all next release.

Comment: Ravi I am using same key store with same password. I have not changed it

Comment: In google api console you have to use  SHA1 KEY that was generate during signed apk generation,Not your eclipse SHA1 key.It will surely work

Comment: Ravi thank you for this answer. But can you guide me how can I update the SHA1 key at google API. becuase its not accepting any update to SHA1 key. There is only another option to get a new client ID. I am afraid if I get a new ID would it work with my Published Game play services.

Comment: you can update it by clicking Edit allowed  references button  at bottom or right side of you key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you upload an apk to play store then for any api that require SHA1 must use SHA1 that was generated during signing process. Not the SHA1 that eclipse  provide.

Try it.

Comment: have you found the Edit allowed references button? @Aiman Batul

Comment: Thanks. I knew this Edit button. But when I click it it does not let me edit my SHA1 Key. its "Edit Settings". I ll try finding it now.

Comment: I found the way. I had to delete the previous client ID and created new with SHA1 key that I get when i Export my android app. It gave me same game ID to use for Google play game service. Just SHA1 key is changed now. I hope it will work fine. Waiting for my app to republish on app store.